# Checkbox JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm working on validating the following code so that onsubmit, the user should have selected at least one checkbox. How would I validate the following checkboxes in JavaScript?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q1"/> I dare you to say the alphabet backwards <br>

  <input type="checkbox"  name="dare" value="q2"/> I dare you to go to a random person and sing twinkle twinkle little star <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q3"/> I dare you to act your true self for a day<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q4"/> I dare you to not shower for a week <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q5"/> I dare you to go vegetarian for 3 months<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q6"/> I dare you to swim with dolphins <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q7"/> I dare you to climb a mountain <br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q8"/> I dare you to not sleep for a day<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q9"/> I dare you to walk backwards through the park <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="dare" value="q10"/> I dare you to jump 50 times. <br>
```

Some of the other validation codes that have been shared on this forum doesn't work for me.

Comment: You mention that other validation code didn't work for you. Can you provide the code for what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you assign a common class to all the checkbox inputs, and then on submit event you iterate thru all the checkboxes with that class to see if any of them is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would validate something like this would be to set a variable to false and loop through all of the options checking to see if they are checked. If you find one that is checked you can set that variable to true and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the inputs, and +1 increment a variable for every checked instance, and if the counter is 0, throw an error.

```
var check = 0;
Array.prototype.forEach(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='dare']"), function(x) {
    if (x.checked) check++;
});
if (!check) //error
```

Faster but prone to more issues but simpler to understand for loop variation:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='dare']");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) check++;
}
```

Comment: Why not just break out of the loop when you find a checked instance?

Comment: You could, but then you eliminate the possibility of deeper validation. Iterating all the options will not slow down your page, so speed is a moot issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($("input:checkbox[name='dare']:checked").length >0)
 { 
    console.log("Atleast One checkbox selected");
 }else {
    console.log("nothing selected");
  }
```

You may find working code here - http://jsfiddle.net/spnfpkxz/

Comment: @PranayKondekar Not allowed to use JQuery.

Comment: I dont see anywhere in question that I dont have to use jQuery

Comment: @PranayKondekar if the question is not tagged with jQuery, and the OP doesn't specifically say "jQuery answers are fine", it's assumed that using the jQuery library is not wanted